# How to tell if it is worth to introduce polynomial terms?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling, linear-model, polynomial

I usually use Akaike's Information Criteria to compare linear models.

This time, I see that with a polynomial term the model's AIC is lower (better) than without it. In fact, the AIC keeps decreasing as we increase the polynomial degree up to 17 poly(var, 17).

My question is, is there any way, standard or not, to tell if the added complexity to the model and the loss of interpretability is worth for what we gain in AIC, or in R-squared?

Also, how can one interpret a term with a polynomial of high degree? If the term is linear it can be understood as the slope, but what if it is a polynomial of 9th degree?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your goal to understand the science or to do predictions as a black box?

Comment: Let's say that I want to do predictions but I must be able to tell how an increase in a variable affects the predicted variable. Sort of like predictions but with an intuition of what is happening.

Comment: If you want to understand it then I think anything much above a cubic is hard to grasp although your mileage may vary. Have you thought of using splines instead?

Comment: Polynomial relationships above a degree of two or three are very rare in reality and usually trying to use high-degree polynomials results in overfitting (are you using AIC with finite sample correction, i.e., AICc?). You should probably look for nonlinear relationships based on the science behind your data instead. A non-parametric model (splines, GAM) is probably a better option if you don't have such information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do predictions then you should cross validate the number of terms.

If you want to be more theoretical, why not include many terms and remove insignificant terms?

Comment: You are suggesting i do cv for the different polynomial degrees I am considering and choose the one with minimal error?

Comment: Exactly. If more of them are close (e.g. Look at std dev in cross Val criterion across folds) then pick the smaller degree.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making ANOVA tables? That way you can at least test if adding a term is significant.

(sorry, this is a comment to your question, not a full answer, but my reputation is below 50, so I can't make a comment yet).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But with anova tables all I get is that the polynomial term of high degree is significant (small p-value) so I think it really does not help much ^^ if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Also, since interpretability seems to be one of your concerns, have you considered treating your predictor(s) as factor(s)? Usually, a factor with appropriate levels captures any non-linearities so you won't have to include any polynomial terms.

Comment: Thats worth considering, will definitely try it. Thanks again :)